# При передачи динамических string-значений через свойство между классами теряется значение С#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Глаз замылен, рассудок затуманен - нужна помощь извне...
В wpf-проекте, написанного через MVVM мне необходимо передать строку из класса MainViewModel в окно MainView. При передачи статической строки, всё отрабатывает корректно - и значение приходит в MainView, затем помещается в textblock и выводится в окне, но с динамикой, где изначально (при запуске программы) приходит null, значение не передается в последствии.
Что я делаю?
Открываю OpenFileDialog и выбираю там файл, его короткое имя помещаю в строку, затем передаю в MainView, но приходит null.
Если не передавать строку в MainView, а сразу вывести в MessageBox - значение верное.
Нуждаюсь в вашей помощи.

```
public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string temp = "some file";
    public string GetTemp => temp;
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        
    }

    #region ОбластьCurrentOpenedFile

    //название файла, открытого кнопкой "Select parser"
    private string shortFilename;
    public string GetShortFilename
    {
        set
        {
            if(shortFilename!=value)
            {
                shortFilename = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("shortFilename");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return shortFilename;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    //Рабочий код
    #region FindFile

    private ICommand findFile;

    public ICommand FindFileCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return findFile ?? (findFile = new RelayCommand(find_execute));
        }
    }

    private void find_execute(object parameter)
    {
        var filename = new DialogService().ShowOpenFileDialog();
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            return;
        }

        //запись в поле для отображения CurrentOpenedFile
        shortFilename = filename;
        char slash = '\\';
        int lastIndexOf = shortFilename.LastIndexOf(slash) + 1;
        string result = shortFilename.Substring(lastIndexOf);
        shortFilename = string.Empty;
        shortFilename = "Current file: " + result;
    }

    #endregion
```

Класс, где реализован INPC

```
public class BaseViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string property = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
        }
    }
```

MainView

```
public partial class MainView : Window
    {
        MainViewModel mvm;

        public string GetSomeInfo
        {
            get => mvm.GetShortFilename;
        }
        public MainView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            mvm = new MainViewModel();

            //help fucntions
            StartClock();
        }

        #region AllForClock
        public void StartClock()
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
            timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
            timer.Start();
        }

        void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tbClock.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
            tbCurrentFileInfo.Text = "Current file: " + GetSomeInfo;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Слова без кода не имеют смысла при такой проблеме, как у вас.

Comment: `необходимо передать строку из класса MainViewModel в окно MainView` - в MVVM вы не имеете права общаться с View слоем напрямую, это должны делать привязки, у вас должно быть публичное свойство. `но с динамикой, где изначально (при запуске программы) приходит null, значение не передается в последствии` - если у вас привязано свойство, то реализовали-ли вы ему `INPC`?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, да INPC реализован

Comment: Ну тогда как сказали выше, показывайте код, где вы все это делаете, показывайте где теряется значение, как оно передается и так далее. Будем смотреть, как вы его реализовали...

Comment: И где он у вас реализован? И где вы этому привязанному свойству задаете значение? Я вижу ReadOnly свойство, не более...

Comment: Как вы оповещаете UI об изменениях в VM? Где то вызываете что то типа `NotifyPropertyChanged(myProperty)`?

Comment: Все еще не вижу [использования где либо свойства](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOb0H.png). Вижу `shortFilename = filename;`, но как по вашему должно вызваться все в `set` свойства?

Comment: добавил недостающие части кода

Comment: Я вам вроде уже указал вашу проблему, не? У вас есть свойство, которое имеет логику в `set`, в этой логике вы говорите интерфейсу "Ей, это свойство обновилось, возьми новые данные!". Но вместо того, чтоб задать значение этому свойству, вы задаете значение полю, которое ничего не делает, лишь хранит значение.

Comment: Я всё еще не понимаю к чему это, так как все значения (если выбирать файлы несколько раз) при проверках дают соответственный верный результат. Стринг не приходит лишь на MainView

Comment: Так, давайте по порядку. 1. У вас совершенно нету MVVM! Почему? Да потому, что вы не используете привязки, вообще! Что такое MVVM - это подход отделения UI от логики, делается эти при помощи деления всего на 3 слоя: Model - слой, который отвечает за данные, будь то чтение файлов с диска, работа с базой данных, отправка запросов на сервер, сокеты и так далее. View - это UI, то, что видит пользователь вашего приложения. ViewModel - это связующий слой, который берет из M слоя необходимые данные, формирует свойства для привязки и обрабатывает все изменения и команды, которые приходят из V слоя.

Comment: View слой не должен совершенно не как быть задействован в логике VM и тем более M слоя, то есть, ваше приложение должно работать также прекрасно и без единой строчки в XAML. Вот возьмите сейчас, удалите все из XAML и посмотрите на ошибки, ваши M и V слои будут их давать? Если да, то у вас нету MVVM. Далее, 2. Свойства, это что-то по типу приватного поля и двух методов `тип GetValue()` и `SetValue(тип value)`, вот когда вы пишете `var result = Свойство;`, то у вас вызывается `Get`, который в свою очередь берет значение из приватного поля.

Comment: Когда вы пишете `Свойство = 123`, то вы вызываете `Set`, который вызывает ту или иную логику и задает значение приватному полю. Вы же в своем коде делаете все в обход свойства, вы напрямую даете значение приватному полю, что не вызывает совершенно не как `Set` свойства, а значит весь код, что у вас в `Set { ... }` не вызывается и вы не оповещаете интерфейс через INPC, он попросту не знает, что это свойство изменилось. Так что, `shortFilename = filename;` меняйте на `GetShortFilename = filename;`, тем самым вы будете работать со свойством, а не приватным полем.

Comment: Исходя из всего этого, вы должны сейчас 1. Задать `DataContext` окну на ваш `MainViewModel` (`DataContext = new MainViewModel()`). 2. Переписать все на привязки! Строка по типу `tbClock.Text` убирается из кода, а в XAML вы пишете `<TextBlock Text = "{Binding ХХХ}" />`, где `XXX` - это публичное свойство из класса, который был установлен как `DataContext`. Ну и 3. Я бы убрал таймер, переписав его на асинхронный `while(true){...}`, но это уже дело десятое... Вот как минимум это все сделайте и будет вам счастье. В `MainView` у вас должен быть только конструктор с `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, извините за потраченное Ваше время. Читал Ваши комментарии, и совершенно не вникал в суть прочитанного. Спасибо Вам. Мои ошибки: 1) не работал напрямую со свойством (как вы и говорили); 2) пытался зачем-то достучаться не по MVVM в MainView к свойству в MainViewModel; 3) не сделал привязку свойства к textblock'у